# How to add dot character to a character in string?

Tags: c++

I want to add '.' character besides another character in a string but I don't know how to do it ? is it possible?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    string input;
    char dot='.';
    cin>>input;
    for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
    {

        if( input[i]>=65 && input[i]<=90)
                {
                    input[i]=input[i]+32;   
                }
        if( (input[i]=='a') || (input[i]=='e') || (input[i]=='i') ||  (input[i]=='o') || input[i]=='y'  || input[i]=='u' )
        {
            input.erase(i,i+1);
        }
        input[i]+=dot;
    }
    cout<<input<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? I think you are using `std::string::erase()` the wrong way. For example, if a vowel is at index 4, you are erasing 5 characters starting at index 4. Is that what you really want? Or do you just want to erase the vowel by itself? And where do you want the dot to appear exactly? Do you want to replace the vowels with dots, or put dots next to vowels? The way you are using `erase()` with the `[]` operator, you have a potential out-of-bounds error. You need to clearify your question.

Comment: My task is to remove all vowels and then put a dot before any remaining character

Comment: Replace your `if (if( input[i]>=65 && input[i]<=90)
                {
                    input[i]=input[i]+32;   
                })` with `input[i] = tolower(input[i])`. You assume ASCII is in use, and that's not guaranteed, plus it's a lot shorter and more readable anyway.

Comment: I can't figure out what the code is supposed to be doing, so it's hard to give a correct solution.  But in general: if there is a one to one translation of characters, use `std::transform`; otherwise, generate into a new string, copying over and transforming as necessary.  (And FWIW: if you are really translating lower case to upper, it's not a one to one translation.  And if you're translating upper case to lower, the problem is incredibly difficult, since you have to know exactly what word the characters are in.)

Comment: @SUE: If you have a run of multiple vowels next to each other, do you want to replace each individual vowel with its own dot, or do you want to replace the entire run with a single dot? It makes a big difference.

Comment: I want to add '.' before each character
ex: tour --> after I remove the vowels it will be tr 
I want it to insert a dot before each character to be : .t.r

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you want something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    std::transform (input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), tolower);

    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < input.length())
    {
        switch (input[i])
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'y':
            case 'u':
            {
                size_t pos = input.find_first_not_of("aeioyu", i+1);
                if (pos == std::string::npos)
                  pos = input.length();
                input.erase(i, pos-i);
                break;
            }

            default:
            {
                input.insert(i, 1, '.'); // or: input.insert(i, ".");
                i += 2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the cpluplus.com reference ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/ )

```
// inserting into a string
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str="to be question";
  string str2="the ";
  string str3="or not to be";
  string::iterator it;

  // used in the same order as described above:
  str.insert(6,str2);                 // to be (the )question
  str.insert(6,str3,3,4);             // to be (not )the question
  str.insert(10,"that is cool",8);    // to be not (that is )the question
  str.insert(10,"to be ");            // to be not (to be )that is the question
  str.insert(15,1,':');               // to be not to be(:) that is the question
  it = str.insert(str.begin()+5,','); // to be(,) not to be: that is the question
  str.insert (str.end(),3,'.');       // to be, not to be: that is the question(...)
  str.insert (it+2,str3.begin(),str3.begin()+3); // (or )

  cout << str << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Also, check these links:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/

Answer (score 0):

Before you try writing the code, you should write a detailed
specification of what it is supposed to do.  With your code, I
can only guess: convert to lower case (naïvely, pretending that
you'll only encounter the 26 unaccented letters in ASCII), then
delete all vowels (again, very naïvely, since determining
whether something is a vowel or not is non-trivial, even in
English—consider the y in yet and day), and finally
inserting a dot after each character.  The most obvious way of
doing that would be something like:

```
std::string results;
for ( std::string::const_iterator current = input.begin(),
                end = input.end();
        current != end;
        ++ current ) {
    static std::string const vowels( "aeiouAEIOU" );
    if ( std::find( vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), *current )
                != vowels.end() ) {
        results.push_back(
            tolower( static_cast<unsigned char>( *current ) ) );
    }
    results.push_back( '.' );
}
```

But again, I'm just guessing as to what you are trying to do.

Another alternative would be to use `std::transform` on the
initial string to make it all lower case.  If you're doing this
sort of thing regularly, you'll have a `ToLower` functional
object; otherwise, it's probably too much of a bother to write
one just to be able to use `std::transform` once.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming you want this input:

```
Hello world!
```

To give you this output:

```
h.ll. w.rld!
```

Rather than trying to modify the string in place, you can simply produce a new string as you go:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    string output;
    const string vowels = "aeiouy";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        const char c = tolower(input[i]);
        if (vowels.find(c) != string::npos) {
            output += '.';
        } else {
            output += c;
        }
    }
    cout << output << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- `<cctype>` is for `toupper()`.
- `<string.h>` is deprecated; use `<string>`.
- Read whole lines with `getline()`; `istream::operator>>()` reads words.
- Use `tolower()`, `toupper()`, &c. for character transformations. `c + 32` doesn’t describe your intent.
- When you need comparisons, `c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'` will work; you don't need to use ASCII codes.
- Use `const` for things that will not change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this old question got bumped back onto the current list, but after reviewing the answers, it looks like all will miss the mark if the input is more than a single word. From your comments, it appears you want to remove all vowels and place a `'.'` before the character immediately prior to where the removal occurred. Thus your example `"tour"` becomes `".t.r"`.

Drawing from the other answers, and shamelessly removing `'y'` as from the list of vowels, you can do something similar to:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string input;
  if (!getline (std::cin, input)) {
    return 1;
  }

  size_t i = 0;
  for (; input[i]; i++)
  {
    switch (input[i])
    {
      case 'A':     /* case fall-through intentional */
      case 'E':
      case 'I':
      case 'O':
      case 'U':
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
      {
        size_t pos = input.find_first_not_of("AEIOUaeiou", i+1);
        if (pos == std::string::npos) {
          pos = input.length();
        }
        input.erase(i, pos-i);
        if (pos - i > 1) {
          input.insert(i, 1, '.');
        }
        input.insert(i-1, 1, '.');
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  std::cout << input << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Your example:

```
$ ./bin/vowels-rm-mark
tour
.t.r
```

A longer example:

```
$ ./bin/vowels-rm-mark
My dog has fleas and my cat has none.
My .dg .hs f.l.s. nd my .ct .hs .n.n.
```